# Visual Studio 2019 .NET Core 5 angular template, error when publish in IIS 10

Tags: c#, angular, visual-studio, .net-core

I am just trying Visual Studio .net core 5 Angular template to test an application. I have added CRUD functionality, with a book entity

```
public class Book
    {
        [Key]
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string Titulo { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string Autor { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(40)")]
        public string Editorial { get; set; }
    }
```

When i run this site in visual studio 2019 with iis express both api run rights and return correctly, but when i publish in IIS 10 or Windows Azure it return error :

```json
"ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): n: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":200,"statusText":"OK","url":"http://localhost:8090/api/Books","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:8090/api/Books","error":{"error":{"description":"Carácter no válido","number":-2146827274,"stack":"SyntaxError: Carácter no válido\n "
```

for book api call. It looks like a json parsing error, but i don't have a special character that could produce this error. This website is published in https://bookswebapiang.azurewebsites.net/
This is code that return json from api, but no idea why it give error:

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Book } from './book.model';
import { HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BookService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:8090/api/Books'  
  formData: Book = new Book();
  list: Book[];

  postBook() {
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, this.formData);
  }

  putBook() {
    return this.http.put(`${this.baseURL}/${this.formData.bookId}`, this.formData);
  }

  deleteBook(id: number) {
    return this.http.delete(`${this.baseURL}/${id}`);
  }

  refreshList() {
    this.http.get(this.baseURL)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => this.list = res as Book[]);
  }

  //refreshList() {
    
  //  this.http.get<Book[]>(this.baseURL).subscribe(result => {
  //    this.list = result;
  //  }, error => console.error(error));

  //}

}
```

Comment: the entities must be the same please try to use a book entity without annotation it's supposed to work fine .

Comment: Thansk, tried but i get same error. It is a very simple entity, in typescript i declare it:     "export class Book {
    bookId: number=0;
    titulo: string='';
    autor: string='';
    editorial: string='';
    }"

Comment: this is your json {"bookId":0,"titulo":"Test","autor":"Test","editorial":"Test"}

Comment: Yes, right, when it works right with IIS express in Visual Studio it return json "[{"bookId":1,"titulo":"Contact","autor":"Carl Sagan","editorial":"Nasa"},{"bookId":8,"titulo":"Título2","autor":"Autor2","editorial":"Editorial2"},{"bookId":9,"titulo":"Título3","autor":"Autor3","editorial":"Editorial3"},{"bookId":10,"titulo":"Título5","autor":"Autor5","editorial":"Editorial5"}]" but in IIS / Azure websites ti return web page content with incorrect header "Content-Type: text/html" so really no idea where look and how to solve this issue.

Comment: did you try to use HttpHeaders with Content-Type as application/json ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, after what i know, there aren't needed. The issue is that in IIS express, when i try direct calling to api http://host/api/Books it return jason correctly, but in IIS when i try http://host/apiBooks it doens't return json it looks like try return index page so i get the error tryin pasing this html like it was json.  Just for test,"this.http.get<Book[]>(this.baseURL, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    }).subscribe(result => {
      this.list = result;
    }, error => console.error(error));" error in IIS 10.

Comment: Finally solved, i miss upload sqlite database file to IIS, when i upload it and set correct path in appsetting it works right. Thanks